# Create dataframe variable whose observations depend on matching criteria

Tags: r

I have two separate dataframes: Data1 and Data2.

```
head(Data1)
  BeginDate    Value      EndDate
 04/01/2002   350000   06/15/2012
 09/01/2001   220000   02/07/2016
 11/01/2016   473000   01/01/2017

head(Data2)
      Date   HPI
01/01/1998   156
02/01/1998   158
03/01/1998   161
         .     .
         .     .
01/01/2017   209
```

I would like to end up with the following:

```
head(Data1)
  BeginDate    Value      EndDate   BeginHPI   EndHPI
 02/01/1998   350000   06/15/2012        158      191
 09/01/2001   220000   02/07/2016        173      199
 11/01/2016   473000   01/01/2017        202      209
```

Where Begin HPI and End HPI are the HPI values returned for:

```
Data1$BeginDate==Data2$Date
```

and

```
Data2$EndDate==Data2$Date
```

respectfully.
I have seen similar requests but I differentiate my question because I do NOT want to use an ifelse statement, or anything else which requires me to write out the dates, because there are so many possible dates. I should note that this is a simplified example b/c my real 'Data1' consists of maybe 400,000 observations and 30 variables.  'Data2' is the real format of that dataset. I am essentially trying to append macroeconomic timeseries to a large panel dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this approach might be helpful:

I changed the data a bit so the dates match:

```
z1
   BeginDate  Value    EndDate
1 04/01/2002 350000 06/15/2012
2 09/01/2001 220000 02/07/2016
3 11/01/2016 473000 01/01/2017

z2
        Date HPI
1 04/01/2002 156
2 02/07/2016 158
3 11/01/2016 161

library(tidyverse)
z1 %>%
  left_join(z2 %>%
              rename(BeginDate = Date)) %>% #merge by begin date after renaming Date to BeginDate in second data frame
  rename(BeginHPI = HPI) %>% #rename HPI to BeginHPI
  left_join(z2 %>%
              rename(EndDate = Date)) %>% #another merge but now for EndDate
  rename(EndHPI = HPI)
#output
   BeginDate  Value    EndDate BeginHPI EndHPI
1 04/01/2002 350000 06/15/2012      156     NA
2 09/01/2001 220000 02/07/2016       NA    158
3 11/01/2016 473000 01/01/2017      161     NA
```

data used:

```
> dput(z1)
structure(list(BeginDate = structure(1:3, .Label = c("04/01/2002", 
"09/01/2001", "11/01/2016"), class = "factor"), Value = c(350000L, 
220000L, 473000L), EndDate = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("01/01/2017", 
"02/07/2016", "06/15/2012"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("BeginDate", 
"Value", "EndDate"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

> dput(z2)
structure(list(Date = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("02/07/2016", 
"04/01/2002", "11/01/2016"), class = "factor"), HPI = c(156L, 
158L, 161L)), .Names = c("Date", "HPI"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```